# JSON doesn't decode using Vue.js/VueResource in Chrome over HTTPS

Tags: json, google-chrome, https, vue.js, vue-resource

I have an application running on Laravel 5.3, Vue.js 1.0.26, and Vue Resource. Within the app I have several components retrieving data from an API within the same app when the components are compiled.

So I'll have something like this:

```
this.$http.get('https://app.com/api/account/').then((response) => {
    this.$set('user', response.data);
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

And then this should get decoded in my Vue data as:

```
user: {
    name: "Miles Davis",
    email: "cool@trumpet.com"
}
```

Looking in Chrome Dev Tools I can see that my requests are sending back JSON properly. However, I've noticed:

1. In Chrome it works fine when I'm **not** using HTTPS.
2. In Chrome if I'm using HTTPS then the JSON doesn't decode properly. It gets stored as:

   `{\"name\":\"Miles Davis\",\"email\":\"cool@trumpet.com\"}`
3. In Safari, the data gets properly decoded regardless of whether I'm on HTTPS or HTTP.
4. If I do use Vue Resource's `response.json()` then Chrome properly decodes the data even over HTTPS.

So, my question is: **Why is this happening only in Chrome over HTTPS?**

Comment: What's the `Content-type`?  Is it `application/json`?

Comment: Yes. The Response Header `content-type` is `application/json`. The Request Header `accept` is `application/json, text/plain, */*`.

Comment: Are the website and API hosted on the same domain?  Are there any CORS issues that come into play?

Comment: The API is on the same domain so CORS shouldn't be an issue here.